# The generalized word problem on groups

Tags: gr.group-theory, word-problem

Given some group $G$ that is generated by $a$ and $b$, each of which has infinite order, and some free subgroup $N$ generated by $a^k$ and $b^k$, is there any algorithm that tells me if some $x \in G$ is also in $N$? If not generally, what about for $k=2,3,4$?

Comment: No, you can assume that $a$ and $b$ have order $k$ and $G$ has unsolvable word problem. Hence $N$ is trivial (a free group on $0$ generators) and there is no way to tell if $x\in G$ is in $N$.

Comment: What if $a$ and $b$ have infinite order?

Comment: The problem in the wording of your question is that you want to require $(a^k,b^k)$ to be a free family, but you say something weaker "*$a^k$ and $b^k$ generate a free subgroup*" which is not what you want. Fortunately Mark's answer interpreted it correctly.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is "no". Take the free group of rank 2 $F=<a,b>$. Take an infinite  recursively enumerable non-recursive set $X=\{u_1,u_2,...\}$, a subset of a recursive set $X'$ of words in $a,b$ satisfying the small cancelation condition $C'(1/12)$ and containing neither $a^2$ nor $b^2$. Take another infinite set of words $Y$ in $a^2,b^2$ satisfying $C'(1/12)$, $Y=\{v_1,v_2,...\}$. Consider the factor group $G$ of $F$ by relations $u_1=v_1,u_2=v_2,...$. Then the subgroup $H$ of $G$ generated by the images of squares $a^2,b^2$ is free and the membership problem for $H$ is undecidable.

The group $G$ is infinitely presented, the question does not ask for a finitely presented example, which is more difficult and I do not know the answer in that case. If rank can be assumed bigger than 2, the question might be manageable.

In the above construction one can replace $a^2, b^2$ by $a^m,b^n$ for any $m,n>1$.

Comment: Can't we just apply the Higman embedding theorem to your construction (which, if I understand correctly, is recursively presented) to get a finitely presented example?

Comment: @HJRW it won't be generated by $\langle a,b\rangle$ which is a requirement.

Comment: Thanks, @YCor -- I missed that.

Comment: Why is the membership problem for $H$ in $G$ undecidable? I don't quite see the argument...

Comment: @Ian: If X' is a recursive set satisfying $C'(1/12)$ and $X$ is a nonrecirsive subset of $X'$ then the problem of whether $x\in X'$ is in $H$ is undecidable.

Comment: One can use a Higman embedding, then embed the f.p. group into a 2-generator f.p. group and make the subgroup generated by squares of generators free. But then the membership problem for this free subgroup will most probably be decidable.

Answer (score 2):

The special linear group is generated by two elements:

*Trott, S. M.*, [**A pair of generators for the unimodular group**](http://dx.doi.org/10.4153/CMB-1962-024-x), Can. Math. Bull. 5, 245-252 (1962). [ZBL0107.02503](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0107.02503).

And the generalized word problem is known to be undecidable for $SL(4, \mathbb{Z}).$

Comment: Notice that in the question, the subgroup $N$ is assumed to be free and, moreover, generated by small powers of generators of $G$.

Comment: True. On the other hand, is it clear that the subgroup generated by small powers of the Trott generators (or some generators obtained from them by Whitehead moves) is *not* free?

Comment: Igor: What I had in mind is that Mikhailova subgroups are never free (they are also not 2-generated). I am unaware of any examples of f.g. free subgroups of $SL(n,Z)$ with undecidable membership problem. Do you know any? The worst distortion I know (for free subgroups) is given by hydra subgroups, where one can realize arbitrary Ackermann functions as distortion functions.

Comment: @Misha Agreed. On the other hand, even deciding whether $k$-th powers of generators generate a free group might be impossible :(