# Membership problem in general linear group

Tags: gr.group-theory, matrices, geometric-group-theory, decidability

This is surely a very well known problem, but I could not find an answer on MO or on Google, so here I am.

Given some finitely generated free subgroup $H$ of $\operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}])$, and some arbitrary $\omega \in \operatorname{GL}_n(\mathbb{Z}[t,t^{-1}])$, is it decidable whether $\omega \in H$? If so, what is the algorithm for checking this?

Comment: No, it's already false in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z})$. Indeed there are uncountably many subgroups, while membership to a subgroup is decidable only for countably many subgroups. In $\mathrm{GL}_4(\mathbf{Z})$ there are even finitely generated subgroups with non-decidable membership problem, this has certainly been mentioned here somewhere.

Comment: @YCor for which subgroups is it decidable? Would it be decidable if $H$ is free?

Comment: Maybe you mean "finitely generated free" otherwise my counting argument applies. It's certainly unknown in general for which subgroups it is decidable. For finitely generated free subgroups I don't know (this could make a reasonable question).

Comment: @YCor—Sorry for the confusion. I am only interested in finitely generated $H$.

Comment: I think this is the same as asking whether a f.g. free subgroup can be more than recursively distorted. I guess it's unknown (but don't know if anybody ever thought about it).

Comment: Actually, since $GL_2(\mathbb{Z})$ is virtually free there are algorithms due to Markus-Epstein and others for the membership problem for f.g. subgroups. For $n>2$ the membership problem is open for f.g. subgroups, I believe, and it's not clear how freeness helps. @YCor, how does distortion connect to the membership problem?

Comment: ... ahh I got it. Enumerate elements of the free group, and look at their images as a subgroup sitting inside $GL_n(S)$. A bound on distortion will enables you to produce a have a complete list of all elements within a ball of radius $m$ inside  $GL_n(S)$.

Comment: Actually, both in $\mathrm{GL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[t^{\pm 1}])$ and $\mathrm{GL}_3(\mathbf{Z})$ I don't know if the membership problem holds for f.g. subgroups, and even for f.g. free subgroups.

Comment: @NWMT exactly. In a f.g. group with solvable word problem, a f.g. subgroup has solvable membership problem iff its distortion function (relative to fixed finite generating subsets) is recursive, iff it's bounded above by a recursive function.

Comment: @YCor: Yes, see the question raised [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/350114/the-generalized-word-problem-on-groups/350123#comment877195_350123). I am quite sure that the existence of free subgroups with non-recursive distortion is an open problem. But, in view of hydra examples, for all practical purposes, the membership problem in free subgroups is undecidable.